# Branch keeps tracking master

Tags: git

Starting recently, my branches are now **by default** tracking and pushing to the remote master, even if I do `git push -u origin branch_name` and even if I use `matching` as my `push.default` option.

```
# --------
# STEP 1
# --------
$ git checkout -b my_branch
Branch my_branch set up to track local branch master.
Switched to a new branch 'my_branch'

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STEP 2: (same behavior BTW with current/upstream/simple)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ git config --global push.default matching

# --------
# STEP 3:
# --------
$ git push -u origin my_branch
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.16 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
To XX:YYY/my_repo
   62d390c..4e4baa1  my_branch -> master
Branch my_branch set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

---

Also, if I try the following for `STEP 2`, I get an error:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/my_branch
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/my_branch' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

I know I can edit `.git/config` manually, but **WHY** doesn't the above work?

---

```
$ git remote -v
origin  XX:YYY/my_repo (fetch)
origin  XX:YYY/my_repo (push)

$ git --version
git version 2.9.2
```

Comment: Did you do a `git fetch` after the push? I would think that would create `origin/my_branch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit is suspicious as the middle line should not occur:

> ```
> $ git checkout -b my_branch
> Branch my_branch set up to track local branch master.
> Switched to a new branch 'my_branch'
> ```

For instance, when I do `git checkout -b foo` in a repository:

```
$ git checkout -b foo
Switched to a new branch 'foo'
```

Note the lack of an upstream setting.  <s>My guess is that your `gco` alias-or-script has `--track` inside it somewhere.</s>  **Edit**: This turns out to be because you'd configured `branch.autoSetupMerge` to `always`, so new branches created from local branches track their local branch.

This is only half of the problem, but if this were not happening, the full problem would not occur anyway.  Hence **one fix is to delete that setting** (the default seems to be what most people mostly want).

---

Addressing the other half of the problem:

> ```
> $ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/my_branch
> error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/my_branch' does not exist
> ```

The problem *here* is literally just what Git is saying: that `origin/my_branch` does not exist.  Well, it doesn't exist *yet*: you need to convince your Git to have an `origin/my_branch`.  Git being Git, there are a lot of ways to do this, but probably one best way, which we'll get to in a moment.

> ```
> $ git push -u origin my_branch
> Counting objects: 8, done.
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.16 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Total 8 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
> To XX:YYY/my_repo
>    62d390c..4e4baa1  my_branch -> master
> Branch my_branch set up to track remote branch master from origin.
> ```

This is where things go wrong: since `my_branch` *already has an upstream setting of `master`* (not `origin/master`, just `master`), your Git asks the other Git to use the name `master`, as if you had run:

```
git push origin my_branch:master
```

As there are no other problems with this `git push`, their side does what your side asks—sets *their* `master` to match your `my_branch`—and then your side does what you asked with `-u`, which is to change the upstream setting from `master` to `origin/master`.  That's not what you *meant* to ask of course.

(And: it seems a little bit evil for your Git to substitute in `master` when that's a *local* `master`, i.e., `branch.my_branch.remote` is just `.`, not `origin`.  But assuming we can't change Git itself...)

I see three easy ways to fix this:

1. Use an explicit remote-side name: `git push -u origin my_branch:my_branch`.  This overrides the current upstream setting, so that your Git asks their Git to write to `my_branch`.  If that succeeds—it should—your Git will now have `origin/my_branch` and will change your upstream setting for `my_branch` to `origin/my_branch`.

   The one drawback here is that if the push fails, your Git won't change the current upstream setting.  Of course this is true in general for `git push -u` (including both of the next two methods, but in those two cases there's no trap left behind for the future).
2. Explicitly *delete* the current upstream setting before running the `git push`: `git branch --unset-upstream my_branch` (or anything equivalent, including editing the `.git/config` file).  Now that there's no existing upstream, your Git won't ask their Git to use the name `master`.

   As soon as your Git asks their Git to create `my_branch` (rather than `master`) on `origin`, we're back to what happens with the first method.
3. Avoid setting your local `master` as the upstream in the first place.  The effect is the same as method 2.

One *hard* way to do this is to fake out your Git: you can create a remote-tracking branch without actually going to the remote.  To do this you will have to use the "plumbing" command `git update-ref`, rather than `git branch`.  If you do, though, you can then use `--set-upstream-to` before the push that actually creates the branch on the remote.  (The other hard way is the trick you used of editing `.git/config` directly, or doing the equivalent with `git config`.  This allows you to set the upstream to something that doesn't really exist yet, since all Git is really doing here is storing *names*.)

Comment: Thanks torek. I tried without the alias (i.g. regular `git checkout -b new_branch` as well to no avail. That's why I had updated the OP quickly shortly after opening the question), and I always get `Branch new-branch set up to track local branch master.`

Comment: Hm, did you configure `branch.autoSetupMerge` to `always`? That might do it.

Comment: Yes!! That was it: `[branch] autosetupmerge = always` in my global `.gitconfig` (home directory).

Comment: It does seem a bit evil and/or wrong for `git push` to use a *local* `branch.$branch.merge` value for the upstream-side name.  Perhaps if `branch.$branch.remote` is not the same as the remote `git push` is using, it should at least warn, or maybe fail, for most push behaviors.

Comment: Thanks. If you update the answer with that info I will gladly accept it.  I removed the option and it all worked the way I was hoping again.

Comment: I think the only question left is why `git push -u origin my_branch` "ignores" my preference to push against `my_branch` on the remote. The only way I got it to work (with `autosetupmerge = always`) was by doing the full `$ git push -u origin my_branch:my_branch`.

Comment: That (why `push -u` doesn't behave better) is particularly unclear since you tried `matching` which should ignore the upstream setting entirely. The Git folks rewrote `git push` as a C program (it used to be a shell script) so it's now harder to see why `-u` does not help here.

Comment: In case there is any doubt, I just re-tried (and confirmed the behavior) with `matching` again..

Comment: That's *probably* a bug.  I get the impression that some of the non-default behavior modes (like `matching` for push, or this autosetupmerge = always setting) are not being tested.  When I get some time (hah) I need to look at the test suite internals.