# When i push a local branch up to the server it doesn't show as tracking

Tags: git

I have a git repo. If I create a local branch, do stuff and then push the branch up to the server, doing a `git branch -vv` doesn't show it as tracking.

If however I pull the repo down fresh, it does show up with `git branch -vv`

I've also tried the following without success.

```
git config --get branch.foobranch.remote

git config --get branch.foobranch.merge
```

If I continue to use that branch, doing multiple push and pulls from the server, everything works so I can only assume that git knows that the branch is tracking the remote somehow. I'd like to know how I can access this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But isn't that tracking information there to begin with?

No: when you create a new branch locally, Git won't assume *where* (to which remote repo) you want to push it.

More specifically, a simple `git push` (without the `-u`) won't set the local config `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`, which are set when a local branch has one upstream branch associated to it.

You have to specify the upstream repo the first time you will push that branch.

That differs from a [`git clone` (man page)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using `git branch -r`), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.

Since a remote tracking branch exist for (for instance) `origin/master`, when `git clone` does checkout `master`, said `master` will automatically be associated with its upstream branch `origin/master`.
See [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

That is why you can directly push from `master` after a clone, but you cannot push directly after creating a new branch (for which there is no `origin/newBranch` remote tracking branch already present in your local repo)

That checkout (tracking automatically the existing remote tracking branch `origin/<branch>`) will set the local config `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`.

Comment: You can push a local branch to origin/newbranch if it doesn't exist. The initial push creates the branch (I assume this is a specific implementation of the server). Any subsequent pull or pushes are done using "remote" as a default. I do this all the time without using "--track"

Comment: @VincePanuccio No, pushing a new branch won't automatically track it. But cloning a repo, a doing a checkout of that same branch will, as I mention in the answer.

Comment: When I create a local branch, I push and it gets created and then I can push and pull from it without entering tracking information. It might not be tracking it in the way you're thinking but there's clearly a link of some kind there. If someone makes a change to the remote branch I can pull it down, without any tracking info.

Comment: @VincePanuccio tracking `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` are set ot (`origin`/`abranch`): I don't see them when I `push`, unless I `push -u`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/38730763/6309. Maybe you have `branch.autoSetupMerge` set to `always`?

Comment: spot on! That's the missing piece I was after. Thank you!

Comment: @VincePanuccio OK, I have edited the answer to make those local config settings more visible.

Answer (score 3):

That's because git like to separate actions.

Pushing a branch is one action
`$ git push origin feature/more_memory`

Setting a branch's upstream is another action
`$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/more_memory`

But git always offers aliases to perform together some commands that you often want to combine, in your case, when pushing a new branch, use:
`$ git push -u origin feature/more_memory`

This will push the branch and set up the tracking information (`-u`).

Comment: But isn't that tracking information there to begin with? I can push and pull from that branch without setting up tracking information explicitly with -u

Answer (score 2):

This is because you need to create(have) upstream also in remote (stash)

it can be done by:-

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/xyz
```

then you need to push -u option (-u must be done for first time , later once upstream branch is tracked u can push without -u option for that branch)

```
$ git push -u origin feature/xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents: it can get annoying re-typing a branch name when you want to push it to remote. After all you've already typed it to create it! Using `HEAD` resolves that. Here's an example:

`$ git push -u origin HEAD`

This will push your current local branch to the remote and track it. After that, using `$ git push` will work fine.

Comment: There's no need to track the remote, it happens anyway. That was the point of my question. If I have a local branch and `git push origin branchname` then pushing and pulling from that branch from that point on works without an issue. Problem is the tracking info is missing, but it still works :)